# How can I get MVVM Light to work nicely with a Grouped Items Page in Metro?

Tags: mvvm-light, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to implement a Metro style Grouped Items Page using the MVVM Light framework following the sample in this blog post but using a ViewModelLocator to provide blendability:

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/winrt-tutorial-mvvm-gridview-semanticzoom.aspx

I have got this working, unfortunately the grid itself is not showing up in the designer (which is the point of me using MVVM Light).  I have bound the title without problem so I know that the viewmodel is bound correctly.

Any ideas please?

Comment: I have investigated this further by using a simple list view bound to an observable collection.  In the designer it is binding to the collection.  I can tell this because I can see the hard-coded textblocks in the datatemplate.  However any textblocks that are bound to a viewmodel property (even if the value is hard-coded) is not showing in the designer :(

Comment: Can you post an example of the xaml that is not working? I think i ran into this and I had the GridView's ItemsSource bind directly to the viewmodel instead of through a CollectionViewSource.

Comment: Filip, @DanRyan, did you manage to get it working? I have same problem here.

Comment: No I have ended up doing a mixture of MVVM light and design time hints i.e. d:Source="{Binding AllGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=Home:HomeVm, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}.  There must be an issue with the metro design binding in WPF or Silverlight you did not need to provide the design hints to get MVVM lights designer support working :(

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  The issue is, if you're using a CollectionViewSource, that it needs to be explicitly, like this:

As MVVM Light injects design-time-services into the viewmodel you'd expect this to pick up your service and push the design-time data through your viewmodel to the UI.  But it doesn't.

You need to give it an explicit design-time instance for this to work:

There is a useful article about [using CollectionViewSource in design mode](http://jack.ukleja.com/using-ddesignsource-for-design-time-datagrid-grouping-with-sample-data/) that may help.